# Possessive with distinct ownership by multiple parties, "please remember to unlock John's and my offices"

Tags: grammaticality

I apologize if this has already been asked, I was unsure how to phrase my question. If I am trying to ask someone to remember to come by unlock the office of my coworker and my own office how would I say it? Would this be correct? "Please stop by when you have a moment and unlock John's and my offices" We each only have one office and so I questioned whether this would be an appropriate way to convey the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: "Please stop by when you have a moment and unlock John's office and mine."

Comment: Thank you that conveys my intent much more clearly!